# Getting information about Uploaded files

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to write an addon for Firefox which displays the current percentage of a file being uploaded to a website (similar to how chrome does it). The problem I am having is that I have never worked with Addons for Firefox so I'm a little confused.

I have looked at the source of [this Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/uploadprogress/) which was released in 2011, and this developer is referencing the following files:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/DownloadUtils.jsm");
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/PluralForm.jsm");
```

Another interesting piece of code I found when going through the source was:

```
Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/http-activity-distributor;1"],
```

I've done a little research on these modules/classes, but I was wondering if in the last ~4 years there has been a change in the technology, and Firefox has made it a little easier to get file upload information.

I know from my experience in web development that you can use `XMLHttpRequest()` and `addEventListener("progress", <function>, false);` but is that possible with Firefox Addons? And would it work with any file uploaded to a site?

I'm pretty lost as you can see, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!!

Comment: This is interesting I support seeing this in the browser. I'm not sure how to go about it but props to you man for exploring it. Keep us updated. It is absolutely possible from addon scope: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIWebProgressListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=nsIWebProgressListener#onProgressChange%28%29/nsIWebProgressListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=nsIWebProgressListener#onStatusChange%28%29

Answer (score 0):

Actually it looks like all the code you need is right in that addon, i took this from that addon you posted from here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/files/browse/125019/file/components/uploads.js#top

```
init: function() {
        //dump(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> INITIALIZED\n");
        // add observer
        var hao = Ci.nsIHttpActivityObserver;
        var _self = this;
        this.observer = {
            observeActivity: function(aHttpChannel, aActivityType,
                aActivitySubtype, aTimestamp, aExtraSizeData, aExtraStringData) {
                if ((aActivityType == hao.ACTIVITY_TYPE_SOCKET_TRANSPORT) &&
                    (aActivitySubtype == 0x804b0005)) { // STATUS_SENDING_TO
                    //dump("UPDATE STATUS: ["+aTimestamp+"] *" + aHttpChannel + "*\n");
                    _self.updateStatus(aHttpChannel, aTimestamp, aExtraSizeData);
                }
                if (aActivityType == hao.ACTIVITY_TYPE_HTTP_TRANSACTION) {
                    switch (aActivitySubtype) {
                        //case hao.ACTIVITY_SUBTYPE_RESPONSE_COMPLETE:
                        case hao.ACTIVITY_SUBTYPE_TRANSACTION_CLOSE:
                            //dump("REMOVE: *" + aHttpChannel + "*\n");
                            _self.removeUpload(aHttpChannel);
                            break;
                        case hao.ACTIVITY_SUBTYPE_REQUEST_HEADER:
                            //dump("CREATE: *" + aHttpChannel + "*\n");
                            _self.createUpload(aHttpChannel);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        Cc["@mozilla.org/network/http-activity-distributor;1"]
            .getService(Ci.nsIHttpActivityDistributor)
            .addObserver(this.observer);
    },
    shutdown: function() {
        Cc["@mozilla.org/network/http-activity-distributor;1"]
            .getService(Ci.nsIHttpActivityDistributor)
            .removeObserver(this.observer);
    },
```

Comment: Thanks I will use this to help find a solution to my use case! :)